# Data structure to manage huge data - in memory indexing

Tags: data-structures, bigdata

Suppose you have a huge data of students. This data is in RAM (around 48 GB).

```
Student has following attributes:
1) RollNo
2) Name
3) Address
```

Now I need to implement three method:

```
getStudentByRollNo(int rollno)
getStudentsByName(String name)
getStudentsByAddress(String address)
```

In what data structure I can keep these students so that these methods can return the results really fast.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a database.

Comment: @bwegs Can't I handle this in memory only?

Comment: This question was asked to me in one of the technical discussion.

Comment: I can't imagine why you'd be storing a ton of data in volatile memory

Comment: I can't imagine where you'd get 48 gigabytes of student information.

Comment: But in any case, a database can certainly be stored in RAM.